# How to modify existing json structure by merging it with new one

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Here i have existing structure like

```
{
    "name": "Parent",
    "hierarchyNumber": "0",
    "children": [ {
            "name": "ParentC1",
            "hierarchyNumber": "1",
            "children": [ {
                "name": "ParentC1C",
                "hierarchyNumber": "1.1",
                "children": []
            } ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And i have new structure like:

```
{
    "name": "Child",
    "hierarchyNumber": "0",
    "children": [ {
            "name": "ChildC1",
            "hierarchyNumber": "1",
            "children": [ {
                "name": "ChildCC1",
                "hierarchyNumber": "1.1",
                "children": []
            } ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add new structure as child in "ParentC1C" and modify the existing structure hierarchy which should be in order with existing structure like below:

```
{
    "name": "Parent",
    "hierarchyNumber": "0",
    "children": [ {
        "name": "ParentC1",
        "hierarchyNumber": "1",
        "children": [ {
            "name": "ParentC1C",
            "hierarchyNumber": "1.1",
            "children": [ {
                "name": "Child",
                "hierarchyNumber": "1.1.1",
                "children": [ {
                    "name": "ChildC1",
                    "hierarchyNumber": "1.1.1.1",
                    "children": [ {
                        "name": "ChildCC1",
                        "hierarchyNumber": "1.1.1.1.1",
                        "children": []
                    } ]
                } ]
            } ]
        } ]
    } ]
}
```

Here i am able to traverse through tree and get the parent element from existing structure and add new structure there with code:

```
function traverseStructure( root, selectedParentElement ) {
    if( root.children && root.children.length > 0 ) {
        for( var k in root.children ) {
            if( root.children[ k ].Id === selectedParentElement ) {
                return root.children[ k ];
            } else if( root.children.length ) {
                return traverseStructure( root.children[ k ], selectedParentElement );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But not able to understand how can i modify Hierarchical level of new structure as expected. Could anyone please help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit strange question is there any **Id** you are checking ??
Made a demo fixing **hierarchyNumber** while traversing, but child is placed @end.

Anyway there is uncomplete info/definition in question to answer exactly.

```js
function put2lastEmpty(root, child) {
    var hierarchyNumber = root.hierarchyNumber;
    while(true) {
        root = root.children[0]; // in case there is just 1 ??
        if (hierarchyNumber == "0") hierarchyNumber = root.hierarchyNumber;
        else {
            hierarchyNumber += ".1";
            if(root) root.hierarchyNumber = hierarchyNumber
            else break;
        }
        if (!root.children.length && child) {
            root.children.push(child); // add child here
            child = null;
        }
    }
}
var root = root();
put2lastEmpty(root, child())
console.log(JSON.stringify(root,null,2))

function root() { return {
    "name": "Parent",
    "hierarchyNumber": "0",
    "children": [ {
            "name": "ParentC1",
            "hierarchyNumber": "1",
            "children": [ {
                "name": "ParentC1C",
                "hierarchyNumber": "1.1",
                "children": []
            } ]
        }
    ]
};}

function child() { return {
    "name": "Child",
    "hierarchyNumber": "0",
    "children": [ {
            "name": "ChildC1",
            "hierarchyNumber": "1",
            "children": [ {
                "name": "ChildCC1",
                "hierarchyNumber": "1.1",
                "children": []
            } ]
        }
    ]
};}
```

Comment: There is unique id for each element "selectedParentElement" this is id for element where we will merge new structure.  Using function traverseStructure i am able to get that element in existing structure and able to insert new structure there. Problem is how to make generic solution where hierarchy number will get modified as per new structure.

Comment: Simple - you can even run this put2lastEmpty function with parent where you place your child probably by parent.children.push(child) and null as child parameters and it will fix them. Result looks same as your suggested. And you do not need last if in and second parameter at all then.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried this

```
function traverseStructure( root, selectedParentElement, child /*child passed as argument*/ ) {
    if( root.children && root.children.length > 0 ) {
        for( var k in root.children ) {
            if( root.children[ k ].Id === selectedParentElement ) {
                root.children[k].push(child)  //fi you find the selected object you push the child
                return root.children[ k ];
            } else if( root.children.length ) {
                return traverseStructure( root.children[ k ], selectedParentElement );
            }
        }
    }
}
```